# How to overwrite a standard HTML tag?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, hugo

I am writing a web site in [Hugo](https://gohugo.io) and [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com) (and learning as I go) and one point is not clear after reading both Hugo and tailwind documentation: how to override standard tags?

As an example: `h1`. Imagine I would like it to apply to it classes `.text-bold` and `.text-xl` (these are Tailwind classes). What is the correct approach:

- using SCSS to `@extend` these classes?

```
h1 {
    @extend .text-xl, .font-bold ;
}
```

→ does not work, the classes are not recognized:

```
Error: Error building site: TOCSS: failed to transform "styleScssSource.scss" (text/x-scss): SCSS processing failed: file "stdin", line 2, col 23: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .font-bold !optional" to avoid this error.
```

- using some Hugo mechanism to replace on the fly `<h1>` with `<h1 class="text-xl font-bold">`? (I do not know if this can be done)
- or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tailwind CSS provides [`@apply`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply) that allows exactly this.

```
h2 {
  @apply font-extrabold text-3xl my-5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Hugo by defining [partials](https://gohugo.io/templates/partials/).

You need to create a file in `layouts/partials` (for instance `layouts/partials/tag.html`) which content is what you want to ultimately have in the HTML

```
<a href="/tags/{{ . }}" class="bg-gray-300 text-sm rounded-full p-1 px-2">{{ . }}</a>
```

This can be then used as `{{ partial "tag.html" . }}` in your code.